# html button not working

Tags: html, button, user-interface

This is simple html code, I've just recently started learning about writing these.
All of the physical attributes are working for this GUI, but some of my buttons are not functional. 1st-works, 2nd-not working, 1st radio-works(sort of, the answer is missing the y information), 2nd radio-not working, 3rd button-not working. Any insight to what I might be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!!

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1"> 
<table>
<tr>
 <td> <b><font color="00FF00">Enter the value for A</font></b> </td>
 <td> <input type="text" name="box1" style="width:100%; background-color:C0C0FF; color:00FF00" size="8" value="0" OnChange=""/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> <i><font color="00FF00">Enter the value for B</font></i> </td>
 <td> <input type="text" name="box2" style="width:100%; background-color:C0C0FF; color:00FF00" size="8" value="0" OnChange=""/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> <b><i><font color="00FF00">Enter the value for C</font></i></b> </td>
 <td> <input type="text" name="box3" style="width:100%; background-color:C0C0FF; color:00FF00" size="8" value="0" OnChange=""/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> <input type="button" name="button1" size="8" style="width:100%; background-color:FFC0FF; color:FF0000" value="Click here to calculate value for X" OnClick="
    var a = parseFloat(document.form1.box1.value);
    var b = parseFloat(document.form1.box2.value);
    var c = parseFloat(document.form1.box3.value);
    var x = ((12*b*b - 4*b*c + ((b*a*c) / (b-c))) / (5-20*a*a)) - 5*a*a*b*b*c*c;
    document.form1.box4.value = x;
   "/> </td>
 <td> <input type="text" name="box4" style="width:100%; background-color:C0C0FF; color:00FF00" size="8" value="0" OnChange=""/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> <input type="button" name="button2" size="8" style="width:100%; background-color:FFC0FF; color:FF0000" value="Click here to calculate Y value" OnClick="
    var a = parseFloat(document.form1.box1.value);
    var b = parseFloat(document.form1.box2.value);
    var c = parseFloat(document.form1.box3.value);
    var y = ((5*a*c ((a*b*c + 2*c*c) / (5*a+b))) / (((1+a*a) / (b+c+1)) + ((1-3*c) / (2*b-4*c-2)))) - 10*a - ((b*c)/2);
    document.form1.box5.value = y;
   "/> </td>
 <td> <input type="text" name="box5" style="width:100%; background-color:C0C0FF; color:00FF00" size="8" value="0" OnChange=""/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> <input type="radio" name="radio1" OnClick="
    var x = parseFloat(document.form1.box4.value);
    var y = parseFloat(document.form1.box5.value);
    var total = x-y;
    document.form1.box6.value = total;
   "/> <font color="00FF00">Select to show X-Y</font> </td>
 <td> <input type="text" name="box6" style="width:100%; background-color:C0C0FF; color:00FF00" size="8" value="0" OnChange=""/> </td>
</tr>
<tr> 
 <td> <input type="radio" name="radio2" OnClick="
    var x = parseFloat(document.form1.box4.value);
    var y = parseFloat(document.form1.box5.value);
    var tot = x*y;
    document.form1.box7.value = tot;
   "/> <font color="00FF00">Select to show X*Y</font> </td>
 <td> <input type="text" name="box7" style="width:100%; background-color:C0C0FF; color:00FF00" size="8" value="0" OnChange=""/> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td> <input type="button" name="button3" size="8" style="width:100%; background-color:FFC0FF; color:FF0000" value="Click to get A+B+C" OnClick"
    var a = parseFloat(document.form1.box1.value);
    var b = parseFloat(document.form1.box2.value);
    var c = parseFloat(document.form1.box3.value);
    var sum = a + b + c;
    document.form1.box8.value = sum;
   "/> </td>
 <td> <input type="text" name="box8" style="width:100%; background-color:C0C0FF; color:00FF00" size="8" value="0" OnChange=""/> </td>
</tr>

</table> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please, do more research about what's causing the problems and try to be more specific about what isn't working right

Comment: I'm not sure how I can be more specific. Someone else understood and I got the help I needed, thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An operator is missing in your second function, between 5*a*c and ((a*b*c... ;

```
var y = ((5*a*c (which operator here) ((a*b*c + 2*c*c) / (5*a+b))) / (((1+a*a) / (b+c+1)) + ((1-3*c) / (2*b-4*c-2)))) - 10*a - ((b*c)/2);
```

Your last button's OnClick is missing "=" sign;

```
<td>
    <input type="button" name="button3" size="8" style="width:100%; background-color:FFC0FF; color:FF0000" value="Click to get A+B+C" OnClick="
    var a = parseFloat(document.form1.box1.value);
    var b = parseFloat(document.form1.box2.value);
    var c = parseFloat(document.form1.box3.value);
    var sum = a + b + c;
    document.form1.box8.value = sum;
   "/>
</td>
```

Comment: I noticed the capitol V when I posted, so I fixed that and some of the buttons are working. We are not using javascript, just simple HTML

Comment: I've updated my answer. About javascript, you're already using it in your calculations, I don't think it matters whether it's in a script tag or not.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the last button. The 2nd button and 2nd radio are still not working. This is for a class, we have been told we cannot use the script tags.

Comment: I've updated my answer one more time. In the second button, operator is missing, add or multiple..?

Comment: Haha, I knew it had to be something simple that I was overlooking! THANK YOU, YOU'RE AWESOME!! I stared at this for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

This code is not valid (you didn't closed all the opened balises). Did you set an action attribute on the form? The event is "onclick". The keyword is "var". You cannot retrieve DOM elements in pure javascript like that, you need to call "getElementById" for example.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: That was only part of the code, I've added the entire code to cut out any confusion. This is not javascript, it's simple HTML.

Answer (score 0):

step into css file
inspect on element open it up on browser
and try removing css properties from other properties until it clickable
there is no  other solution then this
in my case
i had removed   property of other element   which was setted to postion : absolute
and i removed it now it's working
if you still need help don't hesitate to ask

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).